# Add a photo on sphere ARKit Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, arkit

I need to put a photo on a sphere like this image.

[image]

```
guard let photo = container.childNode(withName: "sphere", recursively: false) else { return }
```

Comment: please show us what have you tried and ask an actual question. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try a SCNPlane and adjust the cornerRadius.